# definition of ordered vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, order-theory

An [ordered vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_vector_space) is the pair $(V , \leq)$ where it satisfies the following:

For all $x,y,z \in V, \lambda \geq 0$,

i) $x \leq y \Rightarrow x+z \leq y+z$

ii) $x \leq y \Rightarrow \lambda x \leq \lambda y$

Question: Solely based on the definition, can we deduce that $x \leq y \Rightarrow \mu x \geq \mu y$ for any $\mu \leq 0, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$? In other words, is it true that for any ordered vector space, the inequality will be flipped over if we multiply both sides by a negative number?

Comment: In the definition, you need to specify the field on which your vector space is defined. From the question I assume you are talking about an ordered field (so $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Q}$ for example).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that is true:

Let $x \le y$ and $\mu \in \mathbb R_-$.

Now 
$$(-\mu) \cdot x \le (- \mu) \cdot y $$
 yields (by adding $\mu \cdot x$ on both sides) 
$$0 \le (-\mu) \cdot y + \mu \cdot x$$

Adding $\mu \cdot y$ on both sides gives

$$
\mu \cdot y \le \mu \cdot x
$$
as desired.

Btw. Note that given a linear ordered $K$-vector space $(V, \le)$, we may define a linear order $(K, \preceq)$ that makes $K$ into an ordered field as follows. Fix $v_0 \in V \setminus \{ \underline 0 \}$. Then for $a,b \in K$

$$
a \preceq b :\Leftrightarrow a \cdot v_0 \le b \cdot v_0
$$